# Swift 3+ CABasicAnimation in TableViewRow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this CABasicAnimation code and I want to execute this code to a single row of a TableView. Is this possible? I want to create a shaking effect of a TableViewRow.

```
func shakeView(){
    let midX = tableView.center.x
    let midY = tableView.center.y

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.duration = 0.06
    animation.repeatCount = 4
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: midX - 10, y: midY)
    animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: midX + 10, y: midY)
    tableView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
}
```

Comment: you need get the cell that you want to animate and add the animation in cell.layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you will find the code that shakes a cell when it is tapped (Adjust to what you need). I have changed your method as it was animating the table view not a cell.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseID", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        shakeView(cell as? UIView)
    }

    func shakeView(_ view: UIView?) {
        guard let view = view else { return }
        let midX = view.center.x
        let midY = view.center.y

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.06
        animation.repeatCount = 4
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: midX - 10, y: midY)
        animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: midX + 10, y: midY)
        view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

[image]